# Webpack dev-server proxy with query params

Tags: javascript, api, webpack, proxy, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to [proxy](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-proxy) my a request with dynamic query parameters, but seem to either get a 404 error or no response at all.  This is what I've tried so far:

```
'/services/app/details.json?id=*': {
    target: 'https://website.com/api/v1/potato/',
    changeOrigin: true,
    secure: true,
    pathRewrite: {
      '^/services/app/details.json?id=': '',
    },
}
```

I'm expecting the request from my local machine (`/services/app/details.json?id=2189`) to proxy to `https://website.com/api/v1/potato/2189` however it seems that the `id` is not appended to the target request and results in a 404 error.

I tried using the `bypass` method to append the id myself which instead gives me no response object.

```
'/services/app/details.json?id=*': {
    target: 'https://website.com/api/v1/potato/',
    changeOrigin: true,
    secure: true,
    pathRewrite: {
      '^/services/app/details.json?id=': '',
    },
    bypass(req, res, proxyOptions) {
      const id = (req.query.id ? req.query.id : '');

      const API = Object.assign({}, proxyOptions, {
        target: proxyOptions.target + id,
      });

      return API.target;
    },
}
```

Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this ? @j_quelly

Comment: No sorry I didn't @SakhiMansoor : (